# Can I simplify this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `analyticsrecords`:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
recordDataId | analyticsReferenceDataId | analyticsDataKey | analyticsDataValue
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16 | 114621208-20161122174835   | recordtype   |    Course ID
17 | 114621208-20161122174835   | recordtypeid |    78
18 | 114621208-20161122174835   | pageStart    | Tue Nov 22 2016 17:48:13 
19 | 114621208-20161122174835   |   pageEnd    | Tue Nov 22 2016 17:48:34
```

I want to calculate the time spent on the course by taking time diff of column related to column value 'datavalue' and my query is:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL((SELECT 
                TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, 
                              STR_TO_DATE((SELECT analyticsDataValue 
                                       FROM analyticsrecorddata  
                                       WHERE analyticsDataKey = "pageStart"
                                         AND analyticsReferenceDataId ='114621208-20161122174835'), '%a %b %d %Y %T'),
                              STR_TO_DATE((SELECT analyticsDataValue 
                                       FROM analyticsrecorddata  
                                       WHERE analyticsDataKey = "pageEnd"  
                                         AND analyticsReferenceDataId ='114621208-20161122174835'), '%a %b %d %Y %T')
              )), 0) AS Time_spent,
    (SELECT analyticsDataValue 
     FROM analyticsrecorddata  
     WHERE analyticsDataKey = "recordtypeid" 
       AND analyticsReferenceDataId ='114621208-20161122174835') AS Course_id
FROM 
    `analyticsrecords`
GROUP BY 
    analyticsReferenceDataId
```

Can I simplify this query and make it more efficient? This will take 14 seconds to calculate 17000 rows.

Comment: Can you not simply store data using appropriate data types?

Comment: No we cant, it an analytics data, which can have different type of data, this table join with original events (click, time spent,etc).

Comment: Even when using an EAV model, I still think it's good practice to have separate "spaces" (in this case, "tables") for each data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  courseid,recordtypeid,
            str_to_date(pagestart ,'%a %b %d %Y %T') pagestart,
            str_to_date(pageend ,'%a %b %d %Y %T') pageend,
            timediff(str_to_date(pageend ,'%a %b %d %Y %T'), str_to_date(pagestart ,'%a %b %d %Y %T')) time_on_course
from
(
select  analyticsReferenceDataId,
            max(case when ltrim(rtrim(analyticsDataKey)) = 'recordtype' then analyticsDatavalue end) courseid,
            max(case when ltrim(rtrim(analyticsDataKey)) = 'recordtypeid' then analyticsDatavalue end) recordtypeid,
            max(case when ltrim(rtrim(analyticsDataKey)) = 'pageStart' then analyticsDatavalue end) pagestart,
            max(case when ltrim(rtrim(analyticsDataKey)) = 'pageEnd' then analyticsDatavalue end) pageend
from analyticsrecords
group by  analyticsReferenceDataId
) s
```